# Django: linking users to models in an App (new to django><)

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I am quite new to django, I know little terms... so it will be appreciated if you would answer more specifically how to implement. <3

I am working on a web development assignment about an image sharing platform. functionality involves users upload, download, delete and search images, etc.

recently I have implemented 'allauth' plugin to my site so that users can login in to the site, also I created an app called 'AllImages' with a model - 'Image'.

**MY QUESTION IS:
How can I link the users to 'AllImages' and 'Image', so that the system knows who uploaded a particular image.**
because I want to only let the uploader himself being able to delete his image

I really know nothing about the plugin, its just done by someone haha....

[this is the allauth plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4CTf.png)

Comment: Hi Jose. I can see that you are new to StackOverflow. Usually the way it's done here is that you show us some work/code that you have produced for us to help you solve problems. Don't except people to help write code from scratch. I recommend checking out the Django documentation to get started, it is really well written and clear, so good for beginners like you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

In your Images model add a foreign key field to user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Further you can query something like..

`Images.objects.filter(user=logged_user)` to get all images of this particular user.

[Django auth User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#user-objects)